# Delay modal popup

Tags: reactjs

I need to delay the opening of a Modal window.
I need to make sure that some data is loaded first before the modal is called.

I tried with `async/await`

```
async loadPatientAndBed(data){
    let admission_id = data['beds_status'][0]['admission_id'];
    this.loadPatient(admission_id)
    .then(
        this.showUnitBeds(data)
    );
}

async loadPatient(admission_id){
    await this.props.getPatient(admission_id);
}
```

I tried with a `setTimout`, but it always loads the `Modal` before the data is loaded.
Data is being loaded into Redux so not sure if I could use something like

```
!_.isEmpty(state.currentPatient)
```

or something.

Comment: just create a state in your component, which you set to `true` when you have datas and you want to open the modal

Answer (score 0):

> but it always loads the Modal before the data is loaded

The reason this is happening is because you're executing `this.showUnitBeds` here rather than passing a function to `Promise.then` (assuming `showUnitBeds` is not already a higher-order function):

```js
this.loadPatient(admission_id).then(this.showUnitBeds(data));
```

Since you're using `async/await` already, you can just do this:

```js
await this.loadPatient(admission_id)
this.showUnitBeds(data);
```

Or this:

```
.then(() => this.showUnitBeds(data))
```

Or, as one final alternative, you could make `showUnitBeds` a higher-order function (a function that returns a function):

```js
async showUnitBeds(data) {
  return () => {...}
}
```

But the first approach is the most straightforward and readable.